# Run .exe packaged in .jar

Tags: java, jar, package, embedded-resource, runtime.exec

I am trying to merge 2 programs I have made to one .jar file. One program is a .jar written in java and the second one is an .exe written in c++. I put both files to the new .jar, wrote this code but it didn't work. When this code was exported to .jar and executed neither of 2 files ran and I got error "no main manifest attribute, in merged.jar" in cmd. Though it worked perfectly when run in eclipse.

```
  public class main
    {
        public static void main(String[] args) 
   {
      try 
   {
      Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /c project1.jar");
      Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /c project2.exe");
   }  
   catch(Exception exce)
     { 
     /*handle exception*/
      }
       }
   }
```

Any idea how to fix this or is there another way to do it? I am new to java, so can't think of anything good. Maybe it would be possible to drop these files to a temporary location in windows and delete them after they're executed?

Comment: You cannot run an exe that is inside a jar file. Windows won't find it there.

Comment: What does the EXE do?  What is the advantage of putting a Java app. as wrapper to the EXE?  Why not write that part in C++ as well?

Comment: General tips. 1) Use a consistent and logical indent for code blocks. 2) In every `catch`, add `e.printStackTrace()` as part of it. 3) Copy/paste the error output and use code formatting.  4) In the event that `/*handle exception*/`  is not **literally** the code being used in the exception handler, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the [**JAR File Specification**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/jar/jar.html#Main%20Attributes).

You have to update your MANIFEST file to populate a "Main-Class" attribute with the class that contains you main() method.

Comment: To fix at least "I got error "no main manifest attribute, in merged.jar" in cmd", in that answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
    String filePath = "C:/Path/to/my/file.exe";
    try {

        Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(filePath);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: I would say '+1 for `printStackTrace()`' but for: 1) This resource (the executable) is inside a Jar. So the path stated will not point to it.  No file path can. **It is *not* a file.** 2) Use `ProcessBuilder` to construct the `Process`.  That makes it at least one step easier to: 3) Implement **all** the recommendations of [When Runtime.exec() won't](http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-12-2000/jw-1229-traps.html)

Comment: does not answer the question, the .exe is packaged in the jar, so the path of the exe is related to the path of the jar.